# How does Form populate `value` parameter in Scala Play framework without passing in?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Here is the code I am playing with

```
  def doLogin = Action { implicit request =>
     val loginRequest = loginForm.bindFromRequest.get
   Ok(s"username: '${loginRequest.username}', password: '${loginRequest.password}'")
  }

  def loginForm = Form(mapping("username" -> text, "password" -> text)
      (LoginRequest.apply)(LoginRequest.unapply))

  case class LoginRequest(username:String, password:String)
```

I am confused on how the `.get` was able to retrieve data, in the [source code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Form.scala)

```
def get: T = value.get
```

`get` retrieves the `value`, however the `value` was never populated in the companion object

```
def apply[T](mapping: Mapping[T]): Form[T] = Form(mapping, Map.empty, Nil, None)

case class Form[T](mapping: Mapping[T], data: Map[String, String], errors: Seq[FormError], value: Option[T])
```

since I only passed in `Mapping`

```
Form(mapping("username" -> text, "password" -> text)
      (LoginRequest.apply)(LoginRequest.unapply))
```

But when I

```
print(loginForm.bindFromRequest.get)
```

it does return the loginRequest object, I am confused on where the `value` parameter get populated, as it should be `None` judging from the `apply` method in the companion object of `Form`

Comment: Look at bindFromRequest. It takes an implicit request (which you've provided). That's where the form values come from, not from the call to get. Try replacing "implicit request =>" with "request =>" and see what happens.

Comment: Hmm, `bindFromRequet` returns `Form(play.api.data.ObjectMapping2@66bafde3,Map.` if you chain it with `.get` it uses the method I mentioned in the question, however the method I mentioned returns `value` and I am confused because `value` is not populated